# Is there a way to copy the command history files written & copied simultaneously twice?

Tags: linux, ksh, aix, command-history

This is regarding the `ksh` shell running on both Linux and AIX machines.

Is there a way to copy the command history files written & copied simultaneously twice (shell doesn't allow `HISTSIZE` to be written TWICE).. Also provided only the new & updated entries to be synced.. Deletion should not get synced...

Ex:

1. When user log's in - the shell writes history to file defined in `HISTFILE` variable.
2. Based on above [1] I wanted `HISTFILE` (or) any other option for shell to write the command history simultaneously on another parallel location on the operating system.

So in-case no.1 is deleted by the user & user doesn't know the no.2 backed up location "System admin.'s" can check second one & identify it.....

Answer (score 1):

you can install the `acct` or `psacct` to audit what users are doing in your systems. With this tool comes a command `lastcomm` which can tell you what were commands issued by the user.

There is a very nice tutorial [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-log-user-activity-using-process-accounting.html)

The tool as a lot more auditing functionalities that might be very useful for account auditing.

Comment: Thanks for above details.. But is it possible to automate to retrieve those data as already we have the Secondary logging capturing available.. We just want the Secondary logging to be made available else simultaneously...

Comment: you can make a script using the tool above and store the output wherever you want.

Comment: agreed ... But I am still looking for automation to capture the data end to end without any third party software as like Secondary logging facility..!